# A couple of questions about Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've been learning to program in Java and the one thing I'm having difficulty locking down is an IDE that I actually like! I tried NetBeans, but did not get on with it at all. I've recently been using CodeRunner, which I found on the Mac App Store. I like CodeRunner, but I worry that it might be a bit simplistic. So I've been thinking of trying Eclipse, but there are a couple of things I'm not quite sure about that hopefully someone here can answer.

First of all, I've tried installing Eclipse on my Mac and I'm baffled by the fact that it comes with a folder packed full of program files and not as just a packaged Mac app. I'm not entirely sure what to do with it; are there any Mac Eclipse users out there who can advise me?

My other query has to do with projects. I've worked with a couple of different Java books and they all recommend using a single project to hold all of the java files for the book. Can anyone explain why this is? I would prefer to keep my own folder structure, for example having a separate folder for each chapter. Would I just have a different project for each chapter instead, is that how this works?

My apologies if these are noob questions; I really want to get my head around Java, but need to be able to get comfortable with the IDE ideally first!

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a fairly large topic. As a beginner you will have a hard time with the IDE because it integrates many concepts that you don't yet even know exist. For example build tools and build automation techniques. The reason to allow the IDE to organise your project correctly is so that its build automation knows where things should be. I would recommend NetBeans to a beginner as it's the must user friendly and it does scale to enterprise projects. Eclipse is...complex. There's also IntelliJ which you could try.

Comment: You need everything in the folder, one of the files is Eclipse.app - run that.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I've been playing around with IntelliJ on your advice and it seems a lot more user-friendly than Eclipse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- you can just put it in the Applications folder and use it as a normal application ;)

2- I think it's better to organise stuffs from the same source (in this case your book) in the same project. You can then put each chapter in different packages

Comment: Thanks for this Epi, I've obviously been away from Windows too long!  :)